# Send message between hierarchically equal controllers

Tags: angularjs, controller

This is the HTML (fragment):

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="Header" ng-hide="hideHeader"></div>
<div class="page" ng-view></div>
```

The `.header` has the same controller always, while the `.page` has different controllers based on the route.

The problem is that `hideHeader` is set in the controller for the current URL.

What would be the best way to tell the `Header` controller that the controller for the current route has changed the value of `hideHeader`?

I don't think setting it on the `$routeScope` is the right way. Also, most of the time, the header will be visible, there are very few pages that want to hide it.

Another idea is for that variable to be set in the `config()` method:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{
    templateUrl:'views/hello.html',
    controller:'Hello',
    hideHeader:true
});
```

However, I am not sure that's a proper "AngularJS" way of doing that.

What's my best option?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want the header to be shown on certain pages and not on others, you _could_ make it part of the partial page template on those pages that should have it (e.g. `hello.html` in your example) instead of the main page. This isn't optimal, of course, since the header code would be repeated on several (most?) pages...

Comment: Hm, so you're saying using an ngInclude for those which have it? I'm trying to optimize this for pages which have it, basically only write code for those which don't.

Comment: I was thinking of adding the first `div` element in your example to the HTML of all of the page templates that should have it, i.e. including that first div in the beginning of `hello.html`. But as I said, this would duplicate it to several places and is thus far from optimal. (Especially in your case, when the "default" behavior is to have the header there.)

Comment: Yeah, that would be difficult to maintain especially as the div has other children inside, the above was a simplification. However, using an ngInclude with a partial for the header isn't such a bad idea. I'm still hoping for a nicer one though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd lean towards a service since the Angular team states **"having two controllers that want access to the same data is a classic sign that you want a service."** (One of the places they mention this is in their Angular Best Practices discussion: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY).  And they also discuss services being the right place for shared state (with thin controllers that are the "glue between views and services").

So, something either like this:

```
myApp.service('headerStatus', function () {
    var hideHeader = true;

    this.hideHeader = function() {
        return hideHeader;
    };

    this.setHeader = function(visibility) {
        hideHeader = visibility;
    };
});
```

Then there's a bunch of ways to tie into it, but here's a simple one:

```
myApp.controller('Header', function ($scope,headerStatus) {
   $scope.hideHeader = headerStatus.hideHeader();
});
```

And a fiddle of this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Yxbsg/1/

**Or** potentially you could use a **value**:

```
myApp.value('headerStatus',true);

myApp.controller('Header', function ($scope,headerStatus) {
    $scope.hideHeader = headerStatus;
});
```

Comment: Good point. I'm a bit uneasy to use a service for this because basically it's only this one-time per route change thing and the Header controller basically never changes that value. Just a few (2-3) controllers change it. Also, the issue with both service and value is that views that want the header would have to state so by setting it to false. I was wondering if there's a way to have it only set for routes that want to change it and not need to be unset in routes that have it. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Yea, interesting.  It makes me ponder who should own the knowledge of what routes have a header.  Two ideas come to mind.  You could have a service own that- so it includes a list of which routes need a header.  Then the service checks to see what route is currently active at sets visibility.  Plusses and minuses that kind of centralisation.  Or like you mentioned in your question you could have the route provider own it.  Not sure what's best for you - I'd really think about who feels like the logical owner of that knowledge given your entire architecture.

Comment: Exactly. I can't decide which is more appropriate though. It would make sense for the config of each route to have a flag about that, but I'm not 100% comfortable having a sort of data in the routing data.

Comment: I personally don't mind the idea of the route setting that it needs a header.  But I'd be tempted to have it register that information with the service so the route isn't directly controlling the view.  Then if things get more complicated in the future you can use the service to handle that.  And it makes it clearer to anyone else reading your code what's happening since the service owns the header state.

Comment: That's a pretty good compromise. I'll wait a bit more to see if there's a *perfect* solution we haven't thought about.

Answer (score -1):

You could listen for the `$locationChangeStart` or `$locationChangeSuccess` events in your header controller and then hide it based on the change in the url.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location

From the AngularJS API Docs

```
$locationChangeStart

Broadcasted before a URL will change. This change can be prevented by calling   preventDefault method of the event. See ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on for more details about  event object. Upon successful change $locationChangeSuccess is fired.

Type:
broadcast

Target: 
root scope

Parameters
Param   Type    Details

angularEvent    Object    Synthetic event object.

newUrl: string    New URL

oldUrl:    (optional)    string    URL that was before it was changed.
```

**EDIT**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    // application routes here
}).run(['$rootScope','$location',function($rootScope,$location){
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(evt,newPath,oldPath){
        switch(newPath){
            case '/some/path':
            case '/some/other/path':
            case '/some/more/paths':
                $rootScope.$broadcast('header.hide');
                break;
            default:
                $rootScope.$broadcast('header.show');
                break;
        }
    });
}])
.controller('HeaderCtrlr',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.hideFlag = false;

    $scope.$on('header.hide',function(){
        $scope.hideFlag = true;
    });

    $scope.$on('header.show',function(){
        $scope.hideFlag = false;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Sure, that's an option, but it seems like too complicated for something that should be easier. It would mean my header controller knows which paths should have the header etc. Also, I did **not** down-vote your answer. :)

Comment: It wouldn't have to be in your Header controller, you could set up the listener on the application module in the `run` function and have it `$broadcast` a message on whether or not to hide that only the Header controller listens to.  This way your Header controller wouldn't need to have path information.